# cURL: Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

Tags: curl, php-curl

We are having a strange error. It happens around once every minute and this is what we see in the logs:

`* Connection #0 to host data01 left intact
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* connect to x.x.x.x port yyyy failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port yyyy: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0`

We have data01 correctly defined in our /etc/hosts file but for some reason, the resolved x.x.x.x IP address is incorrect so the connection fails.

curl --version returns the following:

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer of `curl/libcurl` (https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg) stated in [Libcurl Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065002/libcurl-hostname-was-not-found-in-dns-cache):

> The texts about not found in the DNS cache is just junk and is removed in a future version

(Also I doubt that that message is only received by you *sometimes* rather than *always* , i.e. also if you don't experience a timeout- just guessing 
here.)

Make sure `nsswitch.conf` prefers `/etc/hosts`:

`$ grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts: files dns`

Otherwise the wrong IP may be given by the DNS server. Check this by altering your `/etc/hosts` and `$ ping -c1 data01`.